# ubuntu clock applet taking 500 mb memory

Tags: ubuntu

I don't think it's good for clock. I think 5kb would be enough for it. So what's up, ubuntu geeks?

[image: clock-applet memory usage]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've handily covered the "virtual memory" column in your screenshot but nevertheless...

I think you're misinterpreting the "virtual memory" column and would be better looking at the "memory" column. As I understand it, the latter is more representative of what is actually being used, wheras the former is what would be provided if requested.

Note that if you add up all the values in the "virtual memory" column, it far exceeds the physical ram you have in your system.

In this case, your clock applet is *only* taking 10.4MiB.

Comment: An applet that *only* takes 10 million bytes to show the time? Priceless.

Comment: But why the downvote? Yes that's a lot of memory, hence my italicised 'only'. Did I give an incorrect answer? Thanks for the play on my name, I've never heard that witty retort before! :-)

Comment: 1) I don't know, the downvote is not mine; 2) Pun not intended, actually I only noticed it now that you mentioned it.

Answer (score 0):

the clock-applet is using so much virtual memory as it is including several shared libraries, but that shouldn't bother you as these libraries are shared between process.

( But why needs a clock applet libkrb5, libssl, libsqlite3 ??? )

more interesting is the RES memory usage of the clock applet, and you are right 10.4 MB for a simple clock indicator ( its 22 MB now on my Ubunto 10.10 !! ) is incredible !!